# Typescript async / await Promise call difference?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-2016, typescript1.7

If in Typescript 1.7 / ES7 I have three functions:

```
async function f(): Promise<int> { /* ... */ }

async function g(): Promise<int> {
    return f();
}

async function h(): Promise<int> {
    return await f();
}
```

What would be the difference between these calls:

```
g();    
h();    
await g();    
await h();
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling an asynchronous function directly like `g();` returns a `Promise` that can be resolved/rejected:

```
g().then((result) => {
  doSomethingWith(result);
  doSomethingElseWith(result);
});
```

Returning a `Promise` within another `Promise` (which is what `return f();` does) will resolve the outer promise with the value of the inner promise.

Just calling `g()` will start whatever `g` is doing and not waiting for its completion, discarding the result.

Calling `g` with `await` requires the enclosing scope to be an `async` function as well, which *conceptually* "waits" for `g` to "return" (to resolve/reject, actually).

---

Calling an asynchronous function with the `await` keyword does basically the same thing as calling without `await` and using a `Promise`, just with a nicer syntax. So this:

```
async function f () { ... }

try {
  var result = await f();
  doSomethingWith(result);
} catch (error) {
  handle(error);
}
```

is actually the same as this:

```
async function f() { ... }

f().then(
  (result) => doSomethingWith(result),
  (error) => handle(error)
);
```